# Calling a function inside $scope.$watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a directive for creating a dropdown with search feature.
In this directive I have used a flag called 'searchSearchBtn', based on this I am displaying a button.

Ok, let me show my code, for a clear idea,

Angular directive

```
    angObj.directive('largeListSearch', function(domainReports){
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                scope:{
                    selectedObj:"=",
                    listColumns: "=",
                    showSearchBtn:"="
                },
                template: '...'+
                    '<input style="width: 350px;" class="dropdown-toggle inactive dd_txt" ng-model="selectedObj.name" id="campaignDropdown" title="{{selectedObj.name}}" placeholder="{{selectedObj.name }}" />'+
                    '<input type="button" value="Search" id="element" style="display: none" data-ng-click="filterDropDown()" />'+
                    '...',
                link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

$scope.filter = function(val) = {
 //Logic to filter the campaigns
}

                   $scope.originalCampaingList = $scope.$parent.campaigns;

                    //Check the status and load the function accordingly for the campaigns list
                    if(attrs.showSearchBtn === "true") {


                        $scope.filterDropDown = function(){
                            //Function to filter the searched campaign
                            $scope.filter(val);

                        };
                    }else{
                        $scope.$watch('selectedObj.name', function(oldValue, newValue){
                            console.log(oldValue + "  "+ newValue);
                            if(oldValue === newValue) {
                                return;
                            }

                            //Function to filter the searched campaign
                            $scope.filter(val); /HERE Could not able to call the filter function, Is it that, we can not call a function inside $scope.$watch
                            }

                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**My problem : Not able to call the function inside the $scope.$watch**

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$scope.filter(val)`, there is no variable `val` in the current scope. You need to specify a value for `val`. Perhaps you meant `$scope.filter($scope.selectedObj)`?

Comment: dear friend, that is a typo mistake, but my real problem is, the function is not called, where you pass a parameter or not.

Comment: In that case, I'm not really sure what the problem is. Could you provide some more of your code, so that I could test it myself? (e.g. a jsfiddle would be helpful)